# How to store a text-to-speech audio in an audio file (IOS)

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.forms, avfoundation

I am trying to create a video in IOS with Text-to-speech (like TikTok does). The only way to do this that I thought was to merge a video and an audio with AVFoundations, but it seems impossible to insert the audio of a text-to-speech into a .caf file.

This is what I tried:

```
public async Task amethod(string[] _text_and_position)
{
                string[] text_and_position = (string[])_text_and_position;
                double tts_starting_position = Convert.ToDouble(text_and_position[0]);
                string text = text_and_position[1];

                var synthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();
                var su = new AVSpeechUtterance(text)
                {
                    Rate = 0.5f,
                    Volume = 1.6f,
                    PitchMultiplier = 1.4f,
                    Voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.FromLanguage("en-us")
                };
                synthesizer.SpeakUtterance(su);

                Action<AVAudioBuffer> buffer = new Action<AVAudioBuffer>(asss);
                try
                {
                    synthesizer.WriteUtterance(su, buffer);
                }
                catch (Exception error) { }
}
        public async void asss(AVAudioBuffer _buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                var pcmBuffer = (AVAudioPcmBuffer)_buffer;

                if (pcmBuffer.FrameLength == 0)
                {
                    // done
                }
                else
                {
                    AVAudioFile output = null;
                    // append buffer to file
                    NSError error;

                    if (output == null)
                    {
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TTS/" + 1 + ".caf");
                        NSUrl fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath);

                        output = new AVAudioFile(fileUrl, pcmBuffer.Format.Settings, AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMInt16 , false ,out error);
                    }
                    output.WriteFromBuffer(pcmBuffer, out error);
              }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                new UIAlertView("Error", error.ToString(), null, "OK", null).Show();
            }
        }
```

This is the same code in objective-c

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "test 123")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en")
var output: AVAudioFile?

synthesizer.write(utterance) { (buffer: AVAudioBuffer) in
   guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
      fatalError("unknown buffer type: \(buffer)")
   }
   if pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 {
     // done
   } else {
     // append buffer to file
     if output == nil { 
       output = AVAudioFile(
         forWriting: URL(fileURLWithPath: "test.caf"), 
         settings: pcmBuffer.format.settings, 
         commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, 
         interleaved: false) 
     }
     output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)
   } 
}
```

The problem with this code is that "synthesizer.WriteUtterance(su, buffer);" always crashes, after reading other posts I believe this is a bug that results in the callback method (buffer) never being called.

Do you know of any workaround to this bug or any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks for your time, have a great day.

EDIT:
I commented synthesizer.SpeakUtterance(su); as ColeX pointed out and now the callback method is executed. Unfortunately, I can't store my audios in a file yet since I get another error in

```
output = new AVAudioFile(fileUrl, pcmBuffer.Format.Settings, AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMInt16 , false ,out error);
```

ERROR:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type
> 'AVFoundation.AVAudioFile': the native
> 'initForWriting:settings:commonFormat:interleaved:error:' method
> returned nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
> ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error simply shows `An AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice` .

So stop making it speak and write in the same time .

I used your code and  comment out `synthesizer.SpeakUtterance(su);` , error gone .

#### Update

Based on my test , it does not allow to create extra subfolder , so remove the `TTS/` part , just leave the file name alone .

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),  1 + ".caf");
```

Comment: Thanks, ColeX, your answer was helpful to solve the problem mentioned, unfortunately, another problem merged, I edited my original post, could you take a look at it? Thank you so much for your time. (:

Comment: Check my update .

Comment: Thanks for your help ColeX, I have updated my code, and now the ".caf" file is successfully being generated, however, this file doesn't contain the audio specified, it is a 0 seconds-length audio file. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Ok, I just found what I was missing, "AVAudioFile output = null;" should be outside the method, otherwise, it is resetting itself over and over. Thanks for your help ColeX, I am going to mark your message as the answer, have a nice day. (: